# Can i not use namespaces for classes when i implement its members?

Tags: c++

```
    //date.h file
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H
namespace Date{
class Date
{
    private:
            int day;
            int month;
            int year;
    public:

        Date(int day, int month, int year);

        void changeDay(int day);
        void changeMonth(int month);
        void changeYear(int year);

        int getDay(){return this->day;};
        int getMonth(){return this->month;};
        int getYear(){return this->year;};
        void displayDate();


};

}
#endif

        //date.cpp ile
#include <iostream>
#include "date.h"

using namespace Date;
Date(int day, int month, int year)
{
    this->day = day;
    this->month = month;
    this->year = year;
}
void displayDate()
{
    std::cout << "Date: " << this->day << "." << this->month << "." << this->year << std::endl;
}
void changeDay(int day){this->day = day;};
void changeMonth(int month){this->month = month;};
void changeYear(int year){this->year = year;};
```

This is my code and i don't know why but i cannot use that namespace. I get an error that C++ forbids declaration of Date with no type and that the functions are not member functions. Am i doing something wrong or i just can't do what i want?

Comment: Member functions outside of class should be named with class name prefix, like this: ``void Date::changeDay(int day){/*implementation*/}``

Comment: please don't use 'using namespace Date' like that. You should put all your Date methods inside the Date namespace to make it clear to the compiler they *must* go there

Comment: And prefer initialisation over assignment. Your constructor should be implemented as: `Date(int day, int month, int year) : day(day), month(month), year(year) {}`. This is a so-called initialisation list. Note how C++ is actually clever enough to not annoy you with name conflicts if you use one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still need to scope all of your functions with the class name.

```
Date::Date(int day, int month, int year)
{
    this->day = day;
    this->month = month;
    this->year = year;
}
void Date::displayDate()
{
    std::cout << "Date: " << this->day << "." << this->month << "." << this->year << std::endl;
}
void Date::changeDay(int day){this->day = day;};
void Date::changeMonth(int month){this->month = month;};
void Date::changeYear(int year){this->year = year;};
```

When a class member is referenced outside of the body of the class you need to have `class_name::` before the name of the member as it is dependent on the scope of the class.

Comment: So there is no way of getting around that? Gah..oh well now i know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*Date* is not a reserved word by C++.

When you implement your member functions in the .cpp file, remember to prefix each function name with the name of the class and "::" .

So the constructor would be stated as...

```
Date::Date(int day, int month, int year)
{
    this->day = day;
    this->month = month;
    this->year = year;
}
```

And the displayDate function would look like...

```
void Date::displayDate()
{
    std::cout << "Date: " << this->day << "." << this->month << "." << this->year << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: *"Date is not a reserved word by C++."* - That's true, but I fail to see how it's relevant to the question or to the rest of your answer.